# How to drop string after certain point in all elements of list?

Tags: python

I have a large string stored in a list. I only need to extract the URL and dump the rest of the string. How would I do this? The bold is all I need and for every element in the list, the `?` is the cut off where I want to capture the URL. I am not sure if this will the 'u' disappear as well.

lst =[u'**https://images.com/candles.jpg**?asdkfasdkfihawklwie']

Just want to emphasis that I want to drop everything after the question mark including the question mark itself for every element in the list. Only need the URL.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split` with `list comprehension`:

```
L = [x.split('?', 1)[0] for x in lst]
```

As @Martijn Pieters commented faster is use `partition`:

```
L = [x.partition('?')[0] for x in lst]
```

Comment: No, use `str.partition()`, which is faster for a single split. Or at the very least limit the number of splits. Or, in this case, *use a URL parser* to remove a URL component.

Comment: @MartijnPieters where would I insert the 'str.partition()'